# How do i make my card keep the same width:height ratio when i shrink the page?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I realize this must have a rather simple solution but i've been stuck on this problem and i can't seem to make it work.

[This photo shows the card when the screen is full (it has the correct ratio)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lI2t5.png)

[And this photo shows what happens when i shrink the page (the height and weight change)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQE67.png)

Can someone analyze my code and tell me where the mistake is or how i can fix it? Thank you very much in advance.

```css
.book {
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 10px;
  max-width: 250px;
  max-height: 380px;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 12px rgb(0, 0, 0, .7);
  border: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0, .2);
  transform: preserve-3d;
  perspective: 2000px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: left;
  justify-content: center;
  color: #000;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 0px;
}

.cover {
  top: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  transform-origin: 0;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 12px rgb(0, 0, 0, .1);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.cover img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.book:hover .cover {
  transition: all 0.5s;
  transform: rotatey(-80deg);
}

.book-content {
  margin-left: 45px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.book p {
  font-size: 15px;
}

.book p strong {
  font-size: 16px;
}

.book h3 {
  line-height: 15px;
  margin-left: 0;
}

.book-section {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: white;
  padding: 30px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
Wait for the cover image to appear, then hover over it.

<div class="book-section">
  <div class="book">
    <div class="book-content">
      <h3>The Favourite</h3>
      <p><strong>Director:</strong> Yorgos Lanthimos
        <br><strong>Writers:</strong> Tony McNamara & Deborah Davis
        <br><strong>Cast:</strong> Emma Stone, Olivia Colman, Rachel Weisz, Nicholas Hoult...</p>
      <p><strong>Synopsis:</strong> England, early 18th century. The close relationship between Queen Anne and Sarah Churchill is threatened by the arrival of Sarah's cousin, Abigail Hill, resulting in a bitter rivalry between the two cousins to be the Queen's
        favourite.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="cover">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/250/380">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: We need some additional details. It seems clear you want the size of your cards to depend on the amount of text inside, because you have used max-width and max-height rather than width and height. So each card could have a different aspect-ratio ... and you want these individual ratios perserved when the screen gets really narrow? The height and width limits also mean that a card containing a lot of text will overflow ... what do you want to happen in this case? Should the text inside scroll or shrink? Perhaps we need background on the overall design. Please edit your question to improve it.

Comment: start by reading: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/aspect-ratio

Comment: Yes, this is a case to use CSS aspect-ratio.

Answer (score 0):

your code is responsive and very good. but it's too much responsive. you have to control aspect ratio sometimes :)

you haven't too much option for that case. because there is texts in book/div. you cant control too much texts in small div.
i think its better way for it.

```
.book{
min-width: 250px; //optional but i recommend it
aspect-ratio: 250/335;
 overflow:hidden;
 }
```